How to define gradient frametitle text in the preamble of a beamer file
I am sharing the dummy latex file below, in which I am trying to use gradient text in the frame title using the gradient-text package.
When I use
\begin{frame}{\gradientRGB{This is my frame}{255,0,244}{0,238,255}}
...
\end{frame}

, it works fine and gives the desired output. However, defining the gradient environment each time for every frame is cumbersome. So I wanted to define it in the preamble using \setbeamertemplate. Although it works, it gives two unnecessary symbols, {...\ , at the beginning and end of the frame-title text as shown below.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{gradient-text}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\gradientRGB{\insertframetitle}{255,0,244}{0,238,255}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]{This is my frame}
        Lore impsum dolor sit amet...
    \end{frame}
\end{document}


How to get rid of this error?

gradient-text has some limitation regarding expanding content. As a workaround, you could use \frametitle{\gradientRGB{This is my frame}{255,0,244}{0,238,255}}

As documented in the package documentation, the gradient-text package has some limitations with regards to expanding macros in its argument. As a workaround, you could hack the definition of the frame title to smuggle in the gradient text there.
Caveats:

the frame title continuation won't be coloured, but if this is a problem, you could use the end colour of your gradient for it.

you will still need to be careful with macros in your frame title. The limitations outlined in the gradient-text manual still apply.



\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{gradient-text}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{%
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{%
      \gradientRGB{#2}{255,0,244}{0,238,255}%
      \ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0
        \relax{}\space%
        \beamer@insertframetitlecontinuation%
      \fi%
    }}%
    \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
    \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \frametitle{This is my frame}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}



It works. Thank you. Just one more query, if I copy and paste the permeable with the gradient-text package in a .sty file and call the .sty file in beamer, will the code work just fine as it works here??

@user444 Why don't you just try it?
